# Terminal: grep recursive - don't search in symlink contents

Tags: terminal, mac, search, symlink

When searching with `grep -r`, it avoids following symbolic links by default. This is true for directories, but `grep` still inspects the contents of *files* that are symlinks.

For instance, if I have a framework with the following structure:

```
+-- MyFancy.framework
    +-- MyFancy              (symlink to ./Versions/A/MyFancy)
    +-- Versions
        +-- A
            +-- MyFancy      (the actual binary file)
        +-- Current
            +-- MyFancy      (symlink to ../A/MyFancy)
```

`grep -r "string" MyFancy.framework` prints:

```
Binary file ./MyFancy matches
Binary file ./Versions/A/MyFancy matches
Binary file ./Versions/Current/MyFancy matches
```

This causes the search in such structures three times slower.

How can I make `grep` exclude symlinks?

Comment: You can't. Use, e.g. `find . -type f -exec grep -l 'search' {} \;` where `'search'` is whatever you're greping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [*man page* for `grep`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html), there is no *option* to exclude *symlinks*, and therefore an alternative method will need to be applied. One such method is to use `find` to output only *file pathnames* using the `-type t` *option*, where `t` is set to `f` for *regular file*.

Example:

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -l 'search' {} \;
```

Where `'search'` is whatever you're `grep`ing for, and the *output* will be the *relative path filename* of the *file(s)* containing it because of using `-l` with `grep`.

In the example above, `grep` will be executed for each *relative path filename* that `find` passes to
 `-exec`. As `grep` can handle multiple *filenames*, you can change the `;`, at the end of the *command*, to `+` to tell `find` to pass all the matching *filenames* to `grep` at once. Note that if the number of matching filenames is large, then the allowable length of the *command line* could be exceeded.

Also note that `find` has a rather large set of *options*, and as such you may be able to narrow down the *output* passed `grep`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I did read the `man`, but thought `-p` is supposed to do what I'm looking for... just a few clarifications: 1. both `+` and `;` seem to work the same, and `grep` prints the match immediately what am I missing? 2. Is there a difference between `xargs` and `find -exec` here?

Comment: @Elist **1.** `+` will put multiple files as arguments to the same `grep` call for efficiency reasons. **2.** If you use `+` then no there is not a practical difference.

Answer (score 3):

MacOS ships with BSD grep which doesn't seem to support a way to ignore symlinks. You can install GNU grep. Run it with the 'r' flag and it will ignore symlinks.

```bsh
# Install GNU grep
brew install grep

# Run GNU grep, ignore symlinks.
# Brew doesn't replace system grep, GNU grep needs to be called with 2 g's.
ggrep -rl mypattern

# Run GNU grep, follow symlinks
ggrep -Rl mypattern
```